# Do not allow decimal points after 10 digits using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to allow only digits in a text box using regex expression.

- Maximum 10 digits are allowed.
- Maximum 2 digits after decimal point.
- Decimal points after 10 digits are not allowed.

Valid expressions:

```
999999999.22
1234567890
123447899.1
```

Invalid expressions:

```
99999999999
9999999999.12
9999999999.1
99999999999.12
99999999999.1
```

I have tried below regular expression which does all I want expect one thing:
It allows decimal points after 10 digits, which I do not want.
Decimal points should only be valid after a maximum of 9 digits.

```regex
^[0-9]\\d{0,9}(\\.\\d{1,2})?%?$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your regex in three parts: 1 to 10 digits, 1 to 9 digits and 1 decimal and 1 to 8 digits and 2 decimals:

```
^\d{1,10}$|^\d{1,8}\.\d{2}$|^\d{1,9}\.\d$
```

([Proof](https://regex101.com/r/31oDob/3/))

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but above is not working

Comment: Care to explain why not?

Comment: @PatrickHofman you need to put ^ and $ in every OR branch: `^\d{1,10}$|^\d{1,9}\.\d$|^\d{1,8}\.\d{2}$`. As of now, your regex matches arbitrary stuff, like "dd22" (even if partially).

Comment: @KalpeshKoli Don't forget to escape the backslashes or use a verbatim string, i.e. @"…"

Comment: @Patrick it was not working because i did not put ^ and $ in every OR branch , now it is working well thank you very much

Comment: @KalpeshKoli Yeah, sorry. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You could match either 1 - 9 digits followed by 1 or 2 decimals or 1 - 10 digits using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

[`^(?:\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,10})$`](https://regex101.com/r/NWohA7/1)